# How to add pairs in a new dictionary? [Dictionary] and then sum the values for the same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I need in this part of code to add in a dictionary some pairs. For example `afmLine[1]= 0000000001` (which is an id of a company) and cost.And then when in dictionary there are multiple times the same afmLine number i want to sum the costs for this afmLine number.User input is a txt file like this where companyID is "ΑΦΜ" in my file.Company receipts is a list of every receipt that i have made.

---

CompanyID: 000000000000
Pizza: 2   3.15    6.30
spaghetti:  1   7    7

### ribye: 2  40  80

CompanyID: 000000000001
burger: 1   3.15    6.30
spaghetti:  1   7    7

### ribye: 2  40  80

```
product=input('\nGive me the product name: ')
for receipt in company_receipts:
    for line in receipt.split('\n'):
        if product in line:
            seperateLine=line.split('\t')
            Cost=float(seperateLine[3])
            for line in receipt.split('\n'):
                if line.startswith("ΑΦΜ"):
                    afmLine=line.split(' ')
                    afm=afmLine[1]
                    diction=????
```

Comment: “Add pairs” of what? What is in `company_receipts`? Is`1` the company id or is `0000000001` the company id? Please edit your code to be an [mre] which means I should be able to paste it into a file and add NOTHING else then run it and show the result you are getting.

Comment: all of these for loops are running a txt file i need to add in a diction afmLine[1] and cost variable the company id is 0000000001 or a 10digit number

Comment: Yes but I don’t know from your question what is in that text file, do I? - so put an example into your code. Put yourself in the position of someone reading your question trying to understand what the question is about - I certainly don’t.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903500/seperating-the-numbers-from-strings-to-do-the-maths-and-return-the-string-with-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. But, I think this is what you want:

```
product=input('\nGive me the product name: ')
diction = {} # Initialize Dict
for receipt in company_receipts:
    for line in receipt.split('\n'):
        if product in line:
            seperateLine=line.split('\t')
            Cost=float(seperateLine[3])
            for line in receipt.split('\n'):
                if line.startswith("ΑΦΜ"):
                    afmLine=line.split(' ')
                    afm=afmLine[1]
                    if afm not in diction: # Check the item in the dictionary
                        diction[afm] = [] # Initialize the value with an empty list
                    diction[afm].append(cost) # Append the cost to the dictionary

# Calculating the total cost and printing it per item (i.e. id)
for item in diction:
    totalCost = 0
    for cost in diction[item]:
        totalCost += cost
    print(totalCost)
```

You need to initialize the dictionary and then append items to it. Finally, you can again loop through the dictionary and calculate the total cost per id.

Comment: Thank you for very your reply. it helped me a lot. I already have a diction like this
diction={'ΑΦΜ':afm,'cost':cost}.I want the sum of cost for every single afm! and keep the afm one time in my diction

Comment: What do you mean by {'ΑΦΜ':afm,'cost':cost}? Is afm key and cost value in diction? Do you only want to keep the total sum in the dictionary, but not the individual costs?

Comment: afm is the key and cost is different for every afm. But the there are multiple afm that is the same with diferrent costs. I want the sum of these and keep the afm one time

Comment: So, the code that I wrote should do the job for you. In that code, afm is the key for the diction and the value is a list of costs. Every time we check the dictionary and if the specific afm is in the dictionary, we add its cost to the list of existing costs for that afm; otherwise, we add the key and the value to the dictionary.

Comment: ok i agree but why i get this error : 
 for cost in diction[item]:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Oh, OK. I edited the code. You should change 'for item in diction.items()' to 'for item in diction'.

Comment: finally I found the problem thanks for helping again

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for very your reply. it helped me a lot. 
I already have a diction like this 
diction={'ΑΦΜ':afm,'cost':cost}.
I want the sum of cost for every single afm not the total cost!Maybe there are many times the same key in my diction with different costs. and keep the afm one time in my diction